# update multiple record from dataframe into mongoDB with upsert=True

Tags: python, mongodb, dataframe, pymongo, upsert

I have a dataframe of almost 120000 records as follows.
Also I have a mongoDB collection which looks exacly same as below dataframe

```
ItemID ParentID ItemRating ItemPrice Qty
A1     ItemA1   0          12        100
A2     ItemA2   0          15        200
B1     ItemB1   0          20        300
B2     ItemB2   0          25        400
B3     ItemB3   0          30        150
```

Now, I want update and Insert record from my dataframe into mongo collection with following condition

1. If the combination of ItemID and ParentID both are present in the collection then update the remaining columns into mongo collection from dataframe
2. if the combination of ItemID and ParentID is not present then insert new record. 
   Here ItemID and ParentID is more like unique key to check the update condition.

I know this can be done with PyMongo update_many method by setting upsert=true.
but I am not sure how can I do that ?
how should I write my filter condition ?

Regards
Vipul

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use `update_many()` as that takes a single filter criteria which in your case won't work. What you need is `replace_one()` in a loop with upsert=true. Something like:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pandas as pd
db = MongoClient('localhost', 27019)['testdatabase1']
df = pd.DataFrame({'ItemID':['A1','A2','B1','B2','B3'],
                   'ParentID':['ItemA1','ItemA2','ItemB1','ItemB2','ItemB3'],
                   'ItemRating ': [0,0,0,0,0],
                   'ItemPrice ': [12,15,20,25,30],
                   'Qty': [100,200,300,400,150]
                   })

for row in df.iterrows():
    record = row[1].to_dict()
    result = db.testcollection.replace_one({'ItemId': record.get('ItemId'), 'ParentID': record.get('ParentID')}, record, upsert=True)
    print(f'{"Replaced: " if result.modified_count == 1 else ""}{"Inserted: " if result.upserted_id is not None  else ""} {record}')
```

Comment: Thanks for that.
Also could you provide an example in case of single filter criteria ?

Comment: single filter criteria means that you are updating all records that match the criteria. See https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_many

Comment: Hi,
I have already checked that url. But it's not clear to me how can I put a filter condition using dataframe ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with a lot of data, you probably want to condense it into a single database transaction using `bulk_write()` to execute a list of `ReplaceOne` operations that you have compiled with your dataframe criteria. See [PyMongo: Bulk Write Operations](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/bulk.html).